# How to extract values of inner elements using SAXParser

Tags: saxparser

I have a xml file as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<RULES>
    <RULE DESCRIPTION="" DOMAIN="CAE" NAME="Filter1 " TYPE="FILTER">
        <ATTRS>
            <ATTR RULE_NAME="myFilter1" />
        </ATTRS>
    </RULE>

    <RULE DESCRIPTION="" DOMAIN="CAE" NAME="Skip1" TYPE="SKIP">
        <ATTRS>
            <ATTR RULE_NAME="mySkip1" />
        </ATTRS>
    </RULE>

    <RULE DESCRIPTION="" DOMAIN="CAE" NAME="Filter_new " TYPE="FILTER">
        <ATTRS>
            <ATTR RULE_NAME="myFilter1" />
        </ATTRS>
    </RULE>

    <RULE DESCRIPTION="" DOMAIN="CAE" NAME="Skip_new" TYPE="SKIP">
        <ATTRS>
            <ATTR RULE_NAME="mySkip1" />
        </ATTRS>
    </RULE>
</RULES>
```

How can I parse this file using SAXParser (in C++) such that I am able to extract the value of RULE_NAME attribute only if the TYPE attribute has a value "FILTER".

I can do this using the DOMParser but I would like to use SAXParser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("city")) {
        String city = attributes.getValue("data");
        info.setCity(city);
    } else if (localName.equals("temp_c")) {
        String t = attributes.getValue("data");
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(t); 
        info.setTemp(temp);
    } else if (localName.equals("condition")) {
        String condition = attributes.getValue("data");
        info.setCondition(condition);
    }
}
```

you can use to compair attributes as m doing "data" which is the child attributes. hope this works